# Is there a list of supported rabbitmq versions per mass transit versions?

Tags: masstransit

we are using mass transit and would like to upgrade rabbitmq to the next version.

I couldn't find a list of supported rabbitmq version per mass transit versions

I assume that there aren't breaking changes unless a major version changed so it should be safe.

Also we have CI tests that should let us know if something has been broken.

However,
Is there such a list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no list, but any current version of RabbitMQ should work. MassTransit uses [`RabbitMQ.Client`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RabbitMQ.Client) to communicate with RabbitMQ.

Comment: Thanks, Chris, for the quick response!